# What research is there on the effectiveness of teaching languages without explicit grammar instruction, compared to other teaching methods?

Tags: reference-request, teaching-methods, teaching, effectiveness

I found that learning a language without explicit grammar instruction works very well (for me at least, and a few other people I know). The people that I have seen being taught in this way seem to become fluent much faster than people taught with other methods.

I have tried doing research on the topic but I am not a linguist and I do not understand the terminology that the research papers use, and some of it is very confusing. Also, I am a learner, not a teacher.

All I want to know is **how does teaching a language to adults, without explicit grammar instruction, compare to other teaching methods**?

Comment: Could you please explain the difference between this question and your earlier one [Is there any research on "natural" language learning methods?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/5447/800)

Comment: This one is much more specific.

Comment: If you teach using practical dialogues for everyday communication, the dialogues will carry grammar information. So, in a sense, you can't escape grammar. You say you learned a language without it. How specifically did you learn it? Because repetition of dialogue does carry grammatical information so  you always end up with some grammar being "taught", explicitly or implicitly and therefore end up internalizing it.